# Print a custom object on console in extjs

Tags: extjs, logging, extjs4.2

I am trying my hands on extjs 4.2.2 on a UI development. I am totally new to this. I am unable to understand how to print the objects for which i dont know the properties. Can someone please help me out in this.

If i know the property of the object i can do it as below.

```
console.log('print: ' + myObj.get('name'));
```

But if i dont know the property(in this case name) how can get to print it? Is there any way of iterating the object properties and print it. Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can iterate through properties of an object using [for .. in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    console.log("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
```

Another way would be to encode the object to string:

```
console.log(Ext.encode(o))
```

However, I usually log the complete object `console.log(o)` and the I use the console UI to browse through properties of interest.

Answer (score 1):

1. In addition, you might want to consider installing the 'App Inspector for Sencha plugin' from the Google Chrome app store, its a free plug in from Sencha. Very handy, easy to use visual tool to peek under the hood and view components and their methods, properties and values, view what stores exist and the data in them, view the layout, view the events and record which events are getting triggered.
2. Also, worth considering is using Ext.ComponentQuery which I find very useful.  I tend to use this directly in the web browser console window and in my EXTJS console.log statements.

   These links will help explain ComponentQuery
   http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson5/2.cfm
   http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

   http://devjs.eu/en/how-to-use-ext-component-query-in-ext-js-4/